Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
im creating a html form that stores data in a firebase database and when i try to run the code it give this error Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined. i tried to do as the other posts but did not work
im creating a html form that stores data in a firebase database and when i try to run the code it give this error Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined. i tried to do as the other posts but did not work
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import {initializeApp} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-app.js";
      import "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.11.1/firebase-database.js";
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "ddd",
        authDomain: "ddd",
        databaseURL: "ddd",
        projectId: "dd",
        storageBucket: "dd",
        messagingSenderId: "dd",
        appId: "1:ddd"
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // Reference to your 'orderform' node in the database
      const database = firebase.database();
      const orderformDB = database.ref('orderform');

      // Event listener for form submission
      document.getElementById("orderForm").addEventListener("submit", submit1);

      function submit1(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission

        // Get form values
        const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        const item = document.getElementById('item').value;
        const pickupDate = document.getElementById('pickupDate').value;

        console.log(name, item, pickupDate);

        // Push the order data to the database
        const newOrderRef = orderformDB.push(); // Push to 'orderform' node
        newOrderRef.set({
          name: name,
          item: item,
          pickupDate: pickupDate
        });

        // Clear form fields
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
        document.getElementById('item').value = '';
        document.getElementById('pickupDate').value = '';

        // Show success message
        alert('Your order has been submitted successfully!');
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>






Did you see this? The imports there are different than yours.

To add to @tomerpacific answer it is possible to import Firebase using a CDN but the import again looks different than the one you are using. Which tutorial/post did you base this code on?

I tried all these and also tried CDN did not work
